# peity jquery plugin not working on IE 8 with excanvas

Tags: jquery, canvas, svg, internet-explorer-8, excanvas

I am working on jquery plugin called peity which draws charts using SVG. 
[peity](https://github.com/benpickles/peity)
Plotting the donut chart does not work on IE 8.
I tried using excanvas.js but it still does not work.
Any pointers

Comment: What does not work? Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: IE8 does not support SVG and excanvas is canvas for IE8 so why should excanvas allow piety to work on IE8 when it doesn't implement SVG on IE8?